# Determining in emacs the module in which function is defined?

Tags: emacs, ocaml

Say I have the following

```
open A
open List

let double = map (fun x -> 2*x) [1;2;3]
```

In emacs with merlin-mode I can place the cursor on `map` and execute `merlin-type-enclosing` to get the type of `map`.

Is there a similar command (in merlin, tuareg, or others) that can tell me `map` is part of module `List`, rather than `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merlin-locate` (usually bound to `C-c C-l`) will jump to the correct module.

Note: currently this feature doesn't work reliably. *Update: it should work since merlin 2.2*

Comment: I can't get it to work at all. I get "Not found. (Check *Messages* for potential errors)." Checked and there is nothing helpful there.

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about, when I used word "unreliable")) It was working, but it is broken for  now, for most of the libraries. The fix will be soon available.

Comment: A clarification for @jch, this feature works for most of the libraries, and for modules internal to the project. It doesn't work for some library (unfortunately including standard library), since it relies on some files, to be installed.

Comment: it is fixed in merlin 2.2

Answer (score 1):

In the Tuareg menu, you also have a “Show fully qualified ident at point” (bound to `C-c C-l` if `merlin-mode` is not active).  This uses `annot` files so your project must be compiled with that option (set `true: annot` in `_tags` if you use `ocamlbuild`).